# 'simulate' in Enzyme throwing TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing my React Button component using Jest and Enzyme. I need to trigger click on Button. Here is the test code snippet:

```
it('closes cancel modal on click', () => {
  wrapper.find(Button).at(4).simulate('click');
});
```

This throws the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

Removing `simulate('click')` from above code removes the error. I am not sure why this is happening? Any clues?

Here is the React component snippet:

```
         <Button
            uiType="secondary"
            appearance="inversed"
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({
                showCancelModal: false,
              });
            }}
          >
            {i18n('lorem ipsum')}
          </Button>,
```

Thanks.

Comment: have passed props to wrapper ?

Comment: Yes I have passed all required props to the wrapper..

Comment: can you please provide more code to get clear picture.

Comment: You need to provide the stub for `i18n`

Comment: @Satyaki: Removing that doesn't make a difference